# FastAPI with uvicorn and pycord = The future belongs to a different loop than the one specified as the loop argument

Tags: python, discord.py, fastapi, pycord

Trying to run `FastAPI` on `Uvicorn` with `py-cord`
I have some get requests in my code and two discord functions.
Overall program works, discord bot is slower to respond but it gives me this warning/error:

```
ValueError: The future belongs to a different loop than the one specified as the loop argument
```

Trying to run `pycord` with `asyncio` and `FastAPI` lifespan events:

```
@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
    asyncio.create_task(client.start(DISCORD_TOKEN))
    yield
    client.close()

app = FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan)
```

However, if I run `uvicorn` like this:

```
uvicorn.run("main:app", host="0.0.0.0", port=5000, reload=True)
```

This gives no errors. The bot responds instantly.

When switching to production mode:

```
uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=5000, log_level="info")
```

The following error occurs.
Would I need to create a separate thread for the event loop?

I tried all different solutions from forums and github, tried changing asyncio.
Solo `fastapi` works great.

I can't understand what to do next to run them together.

Edit 06/04: I switched to discord.py instead of pycord. Errors is gone.
Hopefully it will help someone

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will work perfectly for your specific case. But I have a fastapi API that runs a discord bot as well. In that API the way I start the bot is by putting in an asyncio task and creating that task when the api startup using `@app.on_event("startup")`

Example:

```
app = FastAPI()

@app.on_event("startup")
async def startup():
    asyncio.create_task(client.start(DISCORD_TOKEN))

# run the uvicorn server normally
```

Comment: Thanks for Your input, gonna save that for later.
I didn't try it tho, after the post was made switched to discord.py instead of pycord:
All is perfect now, no errors :)
Wonder what's wrong with pycord tho